# Meaning of "Modes of inquiry"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am supposed to structure my presentation in the following 6 sections:

- Objectives of the study;
- Theoretical or conceptual frameworks;
- Modes of inquiry;
- Data sources or evidence;
- (Expected) results, conclusions;
- References.

I would like to ask you, what is the meaning of "Modes of inquiry" in simple words?

Comment: Roughly, "modes of inquiry" refers to the ways you use in your studies or to acquire the knowledge, results, and reach the conclusions. (So it depends on what your study is. Your mode might be qualitative or quantitative, it might be creating thinking or studying existing texts, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I thought that you want an alternative term to the *modes of inquiry*. Now I understand that you want the meaning in simple words.

Well, *Modes of inquiry* refers to the holistic approach to looking for some solution/answer and establishing its validity. In other words, you search for the answer and then justify whether it's right. It's a technical term.

[Here](http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/~mohanan/kti/inquiry.htm) is a nice description about it and it's simple.

> Modes of inquiry are the configurations of strategies for (a) looking for answers and (b) establishing their credibility. The former come under “methodology”, and the latter under “justification”. Experiment design, surveys, case studies, fieldwork, quantitative techniques, and the like, are methodologies for gathering information relevant to a research question. The search for patterns and connections, the use of thought experiments, different modes of reasoning (deductive, inductive, analogical, etc), and so on, are methodologies for finding answers through thinking and reflection. Providing justification involves evidence and/or argumentation in support of the answers, and in some instances, evidence and/or argumentation against alternative answers.

Read the whole description about the topic there.